# Formal Languages - Grammar

Tags: grammar, formal-languages

I am taking a Formal Languages and Computability class and am having a little trouble understanding the concept of grammar. One of my assignment questions is this:

Take ∑ = {a,b}, and let n<sub>a</sub>(w) and n<sub>b</sub>(w) denote the number of a's and b's in the string w, respectively. Then the grammar G with productions:

```
S -> SS
S -> λ
S -> aSb
S -> bSa
```

generates the language L = {w: n<sub>a</sub>(w) = n<sub>b</sub>(w)}.

1) The language in the example contains an empty string. Modify the given grammar so that it generates L - {λ}.

- I am thinking that I should modify the condition of L, something like:

  L = {w: n<sub>a</sub>(w) = n<sub>b</sub>(w), n<sub>a</sub>, n<sub>b</sub> > 0}

  That way, we indicate that the string is never empty.

2) Modify the grammar in the example so that it will generate L ∪ {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n+1</sup>: n >= 0}.

- I am not sure on how to do this one. Should that mean I make one more condition in the grammar, adding something like S -> aSbb?

Any explanation about these two questions would be greatly appreciated. I'm still trying to figure these grammar stuff out so I am not sure about my answers.

Comment: A language is a set of "acceptable" or "valid" or "true" words/phrases/strings. A grammar is something that can generate words/phrases/strings. In question 1, you're modifying the language `L`, but that doesn't change that `G` generates the empty string (which is what you're asked to change). In your solution to question 2, your new grammar would generate {w: n_a(w) <= n_b(w)}, which is a way larger set than asked. Because the question is vague ("modify the grammar" doesn't constrain you in any way), you can probably do whatever you like to the grammar. Including rewriting it entirely.

Comment: This might fit better on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The question is about modifying the *grammar* to obtain a new language; so don't modify directly the language…

Your grammar generates the empty word because of the production:

```
S -> λ
```

So you could think of removing this production altogether. This yields the following grammar:

```
S -> SS
S -> aSb
S -> bSa
```

Unfortunately, this grammar doesn't generate a language (a bit like in induction, it misses an initial: there are no productions that only consist of terminals). To fix this, add the following productions:

```
S -> ab
S -> ba
```

2) Don't randomly try to add production rules in the hope that it's going to work. Here you want `a`'s followed by `b`'s. So the production rule

```
S -> bSa
```

must certainly disappear. Also, the rule

```
S -> SS
```

would produce, e.g., `abab` (try to see how this is obtained). So we'll have to remove it too. We're left with:

```
S -> λ
S -> aSb
```

Now this grammar generates:

```
λ
ab
aabb
aaabbb
```

etc. That's not bad at all! To get an extra trailing `b`, we could create a new non-terminal, say `T`, replace our current `S` by `T`, and add that trailing `b` in `S`:

```
T -> λ
T -> aTb
S -> Tb
```

---

I know that this is homework; I gave you the solutions to your homework: that's because, from the way you asked your question, it seems you're completely lost. I hope this answer will help you get on the right path!